# Deploy DACPAC to multiple Databases

Tags: build, azure-devops, dacpac

I have created a release pipeline in VSTS that, as one of the steps, has a SQL server Database deploy task to deploy a DACPAC. The Task essentially executes the sqlPackage.exe in the background.

Our server contains multiple database with the same schema. The databases are named differently however. Is there anyway, in my release pipeline, to deploy the same DACPAC to different databases? I want to avoid having to create a task per database.

Comment: Why do you not want explicit steps for each database? It will help you know which ones have been executed and how many are left. It will also prevent a single failure from stopping all of them.

Comment: Maybe you can create a powershell script that loops over a list of databases and runs the sqlpackage.exe to deploy DAC?

Comment: that's exactly what I did. Thanks

Comment: @user3397856 would you have an example of the powershell you used? I'm struggling to get DacServices to initiate in my script to deploy the dacpac.